# Missing argument for method

Tags: php, arguments

I have to pass a parameter to a function.

```
public function accept($user){

if(! $user){

 //Show not Found page.

 }else{

  //do something else

}
```

If the parameter is empty the NOT Found page is shown but also php errors for missing argument.

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Controller::accept()

Filename: controllers/controller.php
```

What should i do that this errors are not shown? Shall i use php "Getters" and "Setters"? Is there a convinient way to check whether parameters are passed for several functions (instead of writing every time in the beginning of a method "`if(isset($param))`"?

Comment: `public function accept($user=null){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this:

```
public function accept($user){
```

Do this:

```
public function accept($user = false){
```

By using `$user = false` You don't need to add a variable to the function because if it not exists it will be false.

So now you can use these two methods to acces the function

```
accept();
//$user will be false in the function
```

and

```
$idUser = 1;
accept($idUser);
//$user will be 1 in the function
```

Also see for more information about `isset()`, `empty()` and `!` this url: http://kunststube.net/isset/

Comment: what if i want by all means some user-id?

Comment: it is just a example, `$idUser` can be anything you like.